# Movie about a magic school with boy who can shapeshift into eagle or falcon

Tags: story-identification, movie, magic, shape-shifter

It is a live-action movie. I saw it long ago on TV. It was released before 2010 for sure, and probably earlier. The channel was probably TV2 or RTL klub, which are commercial channels in Hungary in Central Europe. Please note that I saw it long ago, so the details are a bit hazy; however, I remember a few very specific moments:

It was about a magic school with wizards. The main character was a boy who can shapeshift into an eagle or falcon. Once he used his shapeshifting skill to annoy his friend. When this happened a teacher reminded him of a story where a man turned into a bear and couldn't turn back and because of this, his own family had to kill him. (This is probably just an insignificant moment in the movie.)

I also remember that in the end there was a key they had to make, which was a puzzle with three pieces. It probably opened some door, and the last piece of the puzzle was a girls' pendant that was in front of them all along.

Comment: So you are certain this was live-action and not a cartoon?

Comment: Sounds a lot like the Earthsea mini series... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earthsea_(miniseries) Don't have time to make it a proper answer, so good luck for the one who does ;-)

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Yes, sorry for the mistake, I was taking this from a friend of mine and I mixed it up, but had him check it and he noticed. Also it should be a movie not a series.

Comment: @akaltar: So the trailer doesn't look like it might match? As a two-part miniseries, it's basically a three hour movie which has probably been shown in its entirety at times.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots It seems like the right one! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is it possible that you're thinking of the [*Earthsea* miniseries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earthsea_(miniseries))?

**Bolding mine**

> In the land of Earthsea, a young wizard named Ged has visions about a girl and doors opening. Meanwhile, King Tygath wants to rule the land and release the Nameless Ones, demons from whom he hopes to learn the secret of immortality. He sends men to attack Ged's village, in search of the wizard of prophesy (Ged). Ged learns his first spell from an elderly woman. When the invasion comes, Ged uses a mist spell and lures the invaders over a cliff, saving the village. However, Ged also falls off the cliff.

....

> A magus named Ogion arrives at Ged's village and revives Ged. He tells Ged his true name and takes him for training, but Ged is too impatient; **he is sent to the magic school on Roke**. There he meets the bully, Jasper, and befriends a student named Vetch.  **Ged shapeshifts into a hawk to show off**. Jasper then challenges him to raise a spirit from the dead, leading him to accidentally release a Nameless One. The demon attacks Ged before being driven away by the Archmagus, who tells him that this Nameless One will hunt Ged down and try to possess him, using Ged's power for further destruction. Ged must go somewhere in hiding until he can find its true name and destroy it.

....

> Vetch finds the tomb first and is taken by the Gebbeth. Ged encounters Tygath in the labyrinth and fights him but then escapes into the tomb. He encounters the Gebbeth and realizes its true name is his own, because it is the darkness in himself. The demon is absorbed into Ged, making him whole again and strengthening him to strike Tygath in the tomb. Tygath forces Tenar to release the Nameless Ones with the incantation. The Nameless Ones are released and take Tygath into the sky before flying off. **Ged reveals part of the key is the second half of the amulet**. The Amulet of Peace is made whole, dispelling the Nameless Ones with a bright light and restoring peace to Earthsea. Ged is seen victorious with Tenar and they kiss.

**Official Trailer**

Comment: The story of the wizard who liked to turn into a bear so often that he eventually became a mindless brute, unable to become a man again is definitely in the book A Wizard of Earthsea, although I don't know specifically if it was in the television series.

Comment: @Buzz: I've got the miniseries playing in the background to see if I pick up on it. :)

Comment: And I gave up on listening to it somewhere partway through the first part. I found the bit with the amulet, but by then, akaltar had accepted it, and I don't think it would be useful to other people particular since as a "the entire movie" link, it will probably be taken down at some point.