# Fantasy novel about a princess in a desert kingdom who was promised to become a priestess or seer of sands

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult

I am trying to find another book from when I was younger early 2000's

This one was about a princess in a desert kingdom who was promised to become a priestess or seer of sands? there are strange creatures that roam the desert and hills, and people believe she was chosen by a goddess at birth. The book starts with her looking at a delicate fountain in the court yard before she is taken away. At the beginning of her training, she is forced to shave her head and bury her fine clothes, hair, and a doll she tried to sneak with her outside. She has a friend who keeps coming to visit her as she struggles to adapt to her new life and it gets her in trouble. Eventually she runs away/escapes from the temple/caves.

I don't remember it being part of a series but I'm not sure. Please help!

Comment: In roughly which year did you read this and can you be more specific about any genuine fantasy elements in this book?

Comment: @LogicDictates early 2000's from a public library

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like [*The Tombs of Atuan*](https://archive.org/details/isbn_9780553101324) from the *Earthsea* series by Ursula K. Le Guin. She has to navigate a maze of dark tunnels by learning all the turnings, and serves some gods called "The Dark Ones". She is given a new name "Arha, the Eaten One" and forgets her real name.

Comment: If this is it (and I strongly suspect it is, although there may be some elements from another work mixed in), it's a duplicate of this one:  https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/172463/young-adult-fantasy-novel-where-young-girl-was-priestess-in-training-in-a-dark-s/